# Queueable Finalizer throwing "ConcurrentPerOrgLongTxn Limit exceeded."

Tags: apex, queueable-apex, transaction-finalizers

We got some 50 mails for `ConcurrentPerOrgLongTxn Limit exceeded.` with heading as `Developer script exception from ******** : Error processing finalizer for queueable job id: 7079G000000HhWs : ConcurrentPerOrgLongTxn Limit exceeded.`

My finalizer has :

```
public void execute(FinalizerContext finalizerContext) {
    if(finalizerContext.getResult() == ParentJobResult.SUCCESS && String.isNotEmpty(queueItem.Status__c) && !queueItem.Status__c.equalsIgnoreCase(QueueItemConstants.QUEUE_STATUS_FAILED)){
        queueItem.Status__c = QueueItemConstants.QUEUE_STATUS_COMPLETE;
    } else if (finalizerContext.getResult() == ParentJobResult.UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION){
        Exception objException = finalizerContext.getException();
        queueItem.Status__c = QueueItemConstants.QUEUE_STATUS_FAILED;
        queueItem.Error__c = 'Failed with exception => ' + objException.getMessage() + ' at line ' + objException.getLineNumber() + ' with stacktrace as => ' + objException.getStackTraceString();
    }
    Database.update(queueItem, false);
    QueueItemExecutor.execute();
}
```

So its just updating the record, the record it self does not have any triggers on update.
Second `QueueItemExecutor.execute();` it tries to execute a logic with some queries on `AsyncApexJob` and two queries with `FOR UPDATE` keyword.

But this should run in async manner as its running from `Finalizer`. So technically how is `ConcurrentPerOrgLongTxn Limit exceeded.` being thrown? Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is very likely not with the code that is experiencing the issue. Somewhere else you have long running transactions gumming up the works.

Comment: Ok, but the error mesage says it failed executing finalizer due to unhandled exception.  Even if concurrent exception is coming from some other code executing finalizer should not have failed.

Comment: If the `Finalizer` hits an exception it cannot handle, it's still going to die.

Comment: To Adrian's point - it seems more plausible that your Finalizer is not contributing directly to the Limit (as it's async), but is impacting other synchronous process to take longer than usual that hits the limit. What object is your `FOR UPDATE` queries on? Are there any other process on that object or that would need that record that could be running at the same time - possibly even due to timing of user activity?

Comment: `FOR UPDATE` is on a custom object which is part of a framework to handle all async requests. But yes this code runs from trigger also, so if there are too many hits to the trigger in one second then this for update may contribute to the concurrent requests.